# PDO - having trouble inserting data using a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a little trouble making something work with a PDO. I will explain as I provide the code.I'm not expecting an answer, but I'm hoping that somebody could provide an explication on what I'm doing wrong and how a correct solution would work like.

I'm working on a CMS and trying to implement a MVC pattern, hence the use of PDOs.

Here is the section of my index.php file  where we have the PDO declaration:

```
<?php
    include_once 'models/USER_mapper.php';

    $USER_mapper = new USER_mapper( 'localhost', 'root', 'root', 'online_magazine' );

    $user = new User();
    $user->setIDUser("JohnnyBoy");

    $USER_mapper->registerUser($user);
?>
```

In the USER_mapper I have the connect function which is called on creation of a new USER_mapper and I also have the registerUser() function which takes a User object as a parameter and it should insert into the DB the info from the User object that was used.
Below is the registerUser() function:

```
public function registerUser($userOBJ) {
    try {
        $q = $this->DBH->prepare ( "INSERT INTO online_magazine.USER_TABLE (id_user, permission) VALUES (:id_user, :permission)" );
        $q->execute ( ( array ) $userOBJ );
        $this->DBH->commit ();
        echo "it works";
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "it doesn't work";
        echo $e->getMessage ();
    }
}
```

The table into which I am inserting has two columns: ID_USER and PERMISSION. Permission's has a default value, which is why I only provide the ID_USER with the setter function and leave the permission blank.

What I'm trying to achieve is to insert data into a table using a User object that has the right values and passing the User object to USER_mapper which will recuperate the info and put it in the respective table.

I hope I have been clear enough to highlight my problem. Let me know if I should add more detail and where.

EDIT1: I forgot to mention that when I use the method above I get a php error that looks like this:

```
[22-Nov-2013 03:18:08 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in directory
```

EDIT2: I found out how to do it using bindParam() as follows:

```
$id_user = $userObject->getIDUser ();
$this->DBH->beginTransaction ();
$stmt = $this->DBH->prepare ( "INSERT INTO online_magazine.USER_TABLE (id_user) VALUES (:id_user)" );
$stmt->bindParam ( ':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute ();
$this->DBH->commit ();
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: Trying to typecast an object as an array is kinda a messy way to do this. Maybe store the data directly inside `$userOBJ` and use a getter like `$userOBJ->getUserData()`?

Comment: By getUserData do you mean have one method in the USER class that will return all the data?(this would resume to what I already did) or just use the getter functions from the USER class to obtain the data?

Comment: You need to write a method that gets the data you want and then returns it. That's what I mean by `getUserData`. Trying to just shotgun your class into your call like that is not only hard to follow but if someone were to add another variable to your class it could break your snippet. Directly pass your data and save everyone from headaches

Comment: I found out how to do it using the bindParam(). Thanks for the help anyway